# Ubuntu 16.10 running slow on new PC with i3 processor

Tags: 16.10

I just built a new PC a modest setup with i3 processor, 8GB of RAM and 2TB HD, nothing crazy.  I installed Ubuntu 16.10 as the OS yet it runs extremely slow, I am a first time Ubuntu user, I have heard it is supposed to run very smooth and quick.  Is my processor to slow, or could I have done something wrong, or so I need to do something else to increase the speed.

```
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 68A0B248-11AC-4013-BD0D-6E50746F589B

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1050624 3890475007 3889424384  1.8T Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  3890475008 3907028991   16553984  7.9G Linux swap
```

---

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

```
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 3907029168 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 68A0B248-11AC-4013-BD0D-6E50746F589B
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907029134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2157 sectors (1.1 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1050623   512.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2         1050624      3890475007   1.8 TiB     8300  
   3      3890475008      3907028991   7.9 GiB     8200 


Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRZ-00Z (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   1992GB  1991GB  ext4
 3      1992GB  2000GB  8476MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: The speed of what ? the interface/GUI ? some task you run ? is the cpu high on usage ?  You don't say much when you say ubuntu is slow ? slow how ? when ? when you do what ?

Comment: when I do anything even move the mouse, or open an app. For example it takes a while for Chrome to open, or Firefox.  It is even slow to scroll through the software store.  Should I have installed 16.04 instead?  Sorry this is my first time using Ubuntu.  I expected with those specs for Ubuntu to run fast

Comment: may be there is a problem with your HDD ? 16.10 is "faster" here than 16.04 on an i3 , 8GB. It should make no difference with &6.04 but you can try it. Is there any task/processus that take high cpu usage as reported by "System monitor" app ?

Comment: The HDD is brand new as well, it is 2TB, could there be anything software related that I missed?  I will stick with 16.10 then, I just want it to run smoothly.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't give more info. like requested above or bnrad of laptop, model and so on....

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?  Anything that could cause it to run slow

Comment: It is a PC I built with I3 processor 3.7GHZ, MSI H110I motherboard, 2 TB hard drive and 8GB of RAM

Comment: What other information would you need?  How do I check for CPU usage on Ubuntu?

Comment: To check the CPU usage - there's an application called "System monitor" (it comes with Ubuntu) which will tell you the CPU usage and what is using the CPU. What graphics card do you have ?

Comment: I am using the one that came with the I3 CPU

Comment: Did you make sure that your disk partitions are properly aligned? Edit your question and include the output of: in terminal, type `sudo fdisk -l` (lower case L) and `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` (also lower case L) and `sudo parted -l` (lower case L). Cheers, Al

Comment: Ok I typed them in terminal and added the results in my question above, I did not partition as I used entire disk

Comment: Did you set your motherboard sata port to the correct speed to match your 2TB hard disk? Using Synaptic, install `intel-microcode` and lets see if updating the processors helps any. In terminal, you can type `dmesg | grep -i microcode` after rebooting, and see if it does any updates. Also check to make sure that you have the latest firmware/software installed for your video card. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

If you use on-CPU graphics adapter (i3-6100 incorporates with Intel graphics 530) try:
Open terminal (command line application, such as cmd in windows)

```
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get upgrade
# sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel
# sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

After that reboot.
I think it could solve the problem

If you use external PCI-e graphics card need to know which AMD/ATI or nVidia were installed.

Comment: awesome, where do I type that in?  Sorry complete nuub here.  And yes i am using the graphics adapter that came with the CPU

Comment: Have you tried the commands that I suggested?